# IE10 - Phantom table borders in print out

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Can anybody identify a solution for this.

IE10 is adding a border around table columns in the print out. They don't appear on the screen or the print preview but only when it's printed on paper or print-2-pdf. Additionly, it only happens when a border is applied that is 2px or larger.  See my test code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:2px solid black;">test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

This will render this when printed to pdf. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rELzq.png

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If it was @media then it should show in the print preview as well. And it would stand to reason that other browsers would render it. Sadly, are no other css styles defined.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only in standards mode? Try switching your Document Mode in Developer Tools (F12).

Comment: Yes, IE is in standards mode.